# What is the Intent to call "Choose screen lock" screen?

Tags: android, android-intent, settings

I cant find any refrence to call the Intent screen "Choose screen lock".

Cant find anything?

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26256974/238753

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

It turns out that this had been added in Version 2.2 of Android.
Please ee pleczko's answer below.

---

Before Android 2.2 there is no intent to do this.

Comment: This is just incorrect. See the @pkleczko answer below.

Comment: @SteveBlackwell You are totally right, it exists since Android 2.2. I have edited my answer to not mislead other people.

Answer (score 39):

You can call **action** `DevicePolicyManager.SET_NEW_PASSWORD` to send user to lock screen settings fragment (firstly he will have to type current password/pattern for secure lock types):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is none. You can view all possible Intents in android's source code: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: What is this Activity?   <activity android:name="ChooseLockPattern" android:exported="false"/>

Comment: Yes there is one, check @pkleczko's answer (DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD)