# handle device's default screen lock behaviour

Tags: android, device-admin

I am using **device default lock screen** in my app for activating and deactivating screen lock. In my application I used a check box which shows that screen lock is activated or not.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
startActivity(intent);
```

I am receiving it callback in my  `DeviceAdminReceiver` class.

Methods:`onPasswordChanged` `onPasswordFailed` `onPasswordSucceeded`

Now if user selects none or press back none of these methods get called. I am not able to identify is screen is locked or not ? I used `OnActivityResult` for handling callback in my Activity, it works fine for back pressed(resultcode 0) but gives same results for all other options.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560076/what-is-the-intent-to-call-choose-screen-lock-screen) link which tells that it can't be handled externally.

**Summary**: I wants to handle screen lock options directly from my application.

Answer (score 0):

if we set password quality on that case user can not able to select none password option 
Might it will help you .
**We can do this in this way**

```
private ComponentName mDeviceAdmin;
private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;

mDPM.setPasswordQuality(mDeviceAdmin, DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING);

Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: if any in inconvinent please let me know

Comment: ...Thanks for the reply... its now disable the option of none,slide and Face Unlock. But it solves the problem to some extent.