# android, Open lock screen settings programmatically

Tags: android, settings, lockscreen

I am creating an app to lock the screen if user has set any lock.
And if he has not set any lock , app will redirect it to lock screen in settings to let user set the lock first.
I have used Device Admin permission to lock the screen and KeygaurdManager.isDeviceSecure method to check if it has been set or not .

But i am unable to find how to redirect user to lock screen programmatically. 
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possible duplicate of this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889399/open-specific-settings-page-programatically)

Have you tried doing this to navigate the user to a specific Settings Page -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
startActivity(intent);
```

For opening the Security Settings use this -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Moreover you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings) the constants for all the possible Actions that you can use in your app to redirect the user to a particular page on the Setting screen.

Let me know if this is not what you were looking for.

Comment: yeah.. that is exactly what i am looking for .

Comment: Glad this was helpful to you.